# Extra await in react breaks async tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, jestjs, enzyme

I have a following piece of code:

```
async fetchAndUpdate () {
  const endpoint = 'endpoint'
  this.setState({ configFetched: false })
  try {
    const response =
      await window.fetch(`https://${window.location.host}/${endpoint}`,
        { method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'same-origin'
        })

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`statusText: ${response.statusText}, status: ${response.status}`)
    }

    // const result = await response.json()
    // if (!result) {
    //  throw new Error(`status: ${response.status}, result: false`)
    // }

    this.setState({ configFetched: true })
    console.log('End of implementation')
  } catch (exception) {
    console.error(`Failed to post data to ${endpoint} endpoint. Error: ${exception}`)
  }
}
```

And I have the test for this:

```
it('should set configFetched when positive response is returned', async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />)
  fetch.mockClear()
  fetch.mockReturnValueOnce(constructSuccessfulResponse(true))

  const fetchButton = wrapper.find(fetchButtonSelector)
  await fetchButton.simulate('click')

  console.log('Here comes the expect...')
  expect(wrapper.state().configFetched).toBeTruthy()
})

const constructSuccessfulResponse = (data) => {
  return Promise.resolve({
      ok: true,
      json: () => data
  })
}
```

And it passes with expected output(first code ends, than expect is checked)

```
End of implementation
Here comes the expect...
```

Problem starts when I uncomment 4 lines from the first snippet.
Test starts to fail, and output is reversed:

```
Here comes the expect...    
End of implementation
```

Why does this particular piece of code change everything? How can I fix this?

Comment: Each `await` yields control, your test isn't actually waiting for the complete operation to finish.

Comment: How can I achieve this?
Getting rid of syntactic sugar and going back to promises is the way to go ?

Comment: For future readers: this book opened my eyes on how async works in JS: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance

Thanks Kyle Simpson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed the problem by putting expect section in setTimeout and by calling done after it's done:

```
it('should set configFetched when positive response is returned', async (done) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />)
  fetch.mockClear()
  fetch.mockReturnValueOnce(constructSuccessfulResponse(true))

  const fetchButton = wrapper.find(fetchButtonSelector)
  await fetchButton.simulate('click')

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(wrapper.state().configFetched).toBeTruthy()
    done()
  }, 1)
})
```

How evil is this?

Comment: since you already use `async` for test function I'd rather put `await Promise.resolve();` right before `expect()...` to it running only after fetch mock has executed.